# how to autopopulate email address with modx FormIt form from a url

Tags: html, forms, modx, formit

I have a website that was done in Modx(yuck) and using FormIt I created a simple page with 1 field, an email textbox.

```
   <form method="post" action="" id="1">
   <label for="advisorName">Email Address:</label><input id="email" type="text" name="email" value=""></form>
```

How can I get the email field populated from an url like:

www.example.com/unsubscribe.html?id=1&email=myemail@address.com

This is easy for me with a standard website, but I am so lost with Modx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a "Snippet", which is just a piece of php code. Call your snippet whatever and something like this should do:

```
return (!empty($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : 'Enter e-mail');
```

Then in your chunk/template or wherever that code you pasted is, change the input value to: `value="[[!NameOfYourSnippet]]"`. The bracers indicate that it's a snippet you want to call and the exclamation mark tells modx not to cache whatever is rendered by it.

Happy modx:ing!

Comment: I actually got this to partially work! you made my day sir! This made a text object that read my value from a link, now to get that value to my text box... thanks again mate!

Comment: it works 100%! I just put [[!mysnipitname]] as the value for my textbox and Viola! Done.

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs - http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/formit/formit.hooks/formit.hooks.email

```
[[!FormIt?
   &emailTo=`[[+addressTo]]`
]]
...
<select name="addressTo">
   <option value="john@doe.com" [[!+fi.addressTo:FormItIsSelected=`john@doe.com`]]>John</option>
   <option value="jane@doe.com" [[!+fi.addressTo:FormItIsSelected=`jane@doe.com`]]>Jane</option>
</select>
```

or if you just need to get email field - http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/formit/formit.tutorials-and-examples/formit.examples.custom-hook

Comment: I have tried this type of stuff til i am blue in the face. Without a workable tutorual i am LOST. i dont know where to put this stuff, and the more i read about modx the more i want to jump off a bridge.